# Custom Settings into an Existing Multi Select Picklist in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, controller, customsetting, multi-select

How to add list custom settings into an existing multi select picklist in visualforce?

VF Page

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1" multiselect="false">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!MyOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Apex:

```
public List<SelectOption> getMyOptions(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();     

    // Reading picklist values and labels
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Investor_Profile__c.Investor_Groups__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    // Adding apicklist values to the select list
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry entry : picklistEntries){
        options.add(new SelectOption(entry.getValue(), entry.getLabel()));
    }

    // Now adding custom settings to the select list
    for(Investor_Details__c setting : Investor_Details__c.getAll().values()){
        options.add(new SelectOption(setting.name, setting.name));
    }    

    return options;
}
```

With this code am getting the picklist values but I need to get the multi select picklist values.

Comment: are you saying that `for(Investor_Details__c setting : Investor_Details__c.getAll().values()){
        options.add(new SelectOption(setting.name, setting.name));
    }` returns no values into the `options` variable?

Comment: On apex:selectList a size of more than 1 and multiselect of true would make more sense. Then also selectedValue on your controller will need to be an array of strings. But perhaps you are asking about something else so please clarify and respond to the comment of @crop1645.